# Points (scatter) on a polygon do not show in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, geospatial, polygon

I would like to draw some (simple) polygons using matplotlib and plot some point over it. The polygons are no problem, but the scatter points do not show. Any suggestions how to fix / correct this?

```
# imports
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

# polygons
gg = {'municipality 1': [(1, 1), (2, 5), (3, 3), (2, 0)],
      'municipality 2': [(3, 4), (4, 6), (5, 8), (6, 3)],
      'municipality 3': [(2, 0), (3, 3), (3, 4), (6, 3), (4, -3)]}

# points / places
gh = {'municipality 1': (4, 2), 'municipality 2': (2, 2), 'municipality 3': (5, 5)}

# set colors
gk = {'municipality 1': 'royalblue', 'municipality 2': 'tomato', 'municipality 3': 'springgreen'}

# figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for gemeente in gg.keys():
    poly = Polygon(gg[gemeente], label=gemeente, facecolor=gk[gemeente], edgecolor='black', linewidth=1)
    ax.add_patch(poly)

for gemeente in gh.keys():
    ax.scatter(gh[gemeente][0], gh[gemeente][1], c='black', label=gemeente)

ax.legend()

plt.autoscale()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The points are there, but hidden under the polygons. You can use the `zorder` parameter to set which plot is on top:

```py
for gemeente in gg:
    poly = Polygon(gg[gemeente], label=gemeente, facecolor=gk[gemeente], edgecolor='black', linewidth=1, zorder=1)
    ax.add_patch(poly)
    ax.scatter(gh[gemeente][0], gh[gemeente][1], c='black', label=gemeente, zorder=2)
```

[image]